# How to control/modify the activity stack in my case

Tags: android, android-activity

I have following activity stack: A->B->C->D

In activity D, a new Activity E will be launched. Is that possible to change the activity stack to A->E (so if user press back they will go to activity A)?

Additional information: I don't want D,E depends on A. So override E's onBackPressed to start A directly or start A from D with CLEAR_TOP flag and then go to E is not a choice.

Comment: dint get your question what actually you want if activity E is launched and user press back you want to be in Activity A?

Comment: @Pavan yes, that is what I want

Comment: Set flag `Intent.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP` while move to `A` activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok as per your requirement it is possible using startactivityforresult and onActivityResult let me explain

1.first call A to B 
2.from B call startactivityforresult C, also in B add  onActivityResult to handle result
3.from C call D as step 2.
4. Now when you call E from D just finish D and setResult(RESULT_OK)
6.Now in activity C onActivityResult get called there check for result ok and finish activity and setResult(RESULT_OK) same for B

here you get stack A to E.

for more info http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html
if any problem let me know

Comment: Thanks Pavan. This solution looks good. The only cons is that I need to modify the B, C, D code. I will accept the answer 1 days later if there is not better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage both your stack and your back pressed buttons by overriding the `onBackPressed` method and by using [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) or not.

So within backpressed methods:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, YourChosenClass.class));
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

> A task is a cohesive unit that can move to the "background" when users begin a new task or go to the Home screen, via the Home button. While in the background, all the activities in the task are stopped, but the back stack for the task remains intact—the task has simply lost focus while another task takes place, as shown in figure 2. A task can then return to the "foreground" so users can pick up where they left off. Suppose, for example, that the current task (Task A) has three activities in its stack—two under the current activity.

Activities linked with a task will be available in the back stack.

Comment: Thanks Yvette. I have edited my question. I don't want E depends on A.